# Text file is overwritten on Ubuntu but appended in Windows

Tags: java, file-io, append

I am creating a file and send it back to the web browser like that :

```
    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddMMyyyy");
File file = new File("VE_ximport_"+dateLivraison.toString(fmt2)+".txt");

    FileWriterWithEncoding writer;  
    writer = new FileWriterWithEncoding(file,"UTF-8", true);
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(writer);
    for (Object[] obj : results){
       //handle data 
       printer.write(data);
    }
    printer.close();
```

I call this function several times and each time the file is overwritten.
It is the behaviour I am looking for.
It works on Ubuntu.
But on a Windows Server 2012 R2, each time I call the function, it appends the data to the existing file.
Even if I restart server between each call, the file is appended, no new file is created.

I m getting mad...
Where am I wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear which file do you mean but if you're asking about file you create at this line:

writer = new FileWriterWithEncoding(file,"UTF-8", true)

Just use false for second argument so it will be overwritten every time.

Comment: User seems to want to create new file every time and not to override or append existing file. your answer does not answer the question

Comment: Actually if the files a re created the same they must replace the existing one. writer = new FileWriterWithEncoding(file,"UTF-8", true) works fine. But I don't know why it behaves differently on Ubuntu. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to create the same name for your file every time so long as you do it on the same day - because you convert your date variable "dateLivraison" using mask "ddMMyyyy". Typical solution is to take current timestamp and convert it to String that would reflect not only date but time up to seconds or milliseconds. That would ensure uniqueness of the created filename.